how to set audio output device for ffplay on Windows?
I try to use this code to setup audio output device:
ffplay -audio_device "Speakers (Realtek High Definition Audio)" "C:\Users\me\Desktop\file.mp3"

but it does not work;
I have been looking and searching many websites, but nowhere could find proper syntax for Windows;
And how to change audio output for another device, e.g -> Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable)
Can somebody help me?
Thanks

First press Windows + R and type mmsys.cpl in the run command. Next go to the recording tab and make sure Stereo Mixer is enabled.
Type this command to check how your audio devices are recognized:
ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy

Copy the friendly or the alternative name of the device you want to record and use a command like this:
ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Your audio device name" -y output.mp3

To stop the recording press Q key or set a time limit you want to use with -t 60 or something like that.
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop

It is not exactly what I want. I want to choose output device in same way as we do e.g. on VLC media player. I have the file.mp3 to play, and I can choose output from VLC menu: Audio -> Audio Device -> list of devices to choose from. So I can choose e.g. Line 1 (Virtual Audio Cable). I need in same way do it using ffplay(ffmpeg) to play my file.mp3 trough e.g. Line 1 (or Speakers or different Line x) as an output device.
